# Checkout hangs because of: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'US' of undefined

Tags: magento-2.1.3

Running a Magento 2.1.3 store. The checkout never fully loads as an error is being generated on post-code.js in (Chrome):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'US' of undefined
at UiClass.update (post-code.js:32)
at setNested (objects.js:43)
at Object.nested (objects.js:117)
at UiClass.set (element.js:301)
at updateValue (links.js:57)
at setLink (links.js:144)
at links.js:165
at Registry._resolveRequest (registry.js:413)
at Registry._addRequest (registry.js:380)
at Registry.get (registry.js:224)
```

And in Firefox:

```
TypeError: options is undefined
```

The lines that that references are:

```
var country = registry.get(this.parentName + '.' + 'country_id'),
            options = country.indexedOptions,
            option;

        if (!value) {
            return;
        }

        option = options[value];
```

I haven't managed to find any similar problems online and have really gotten stock.

Any advise welcome.

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2933

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately these issues do not seem to be related.